# Starcraft2 - Terran: do they have any observer or other way to detect burrowed zerg units (especially banelings)?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

I usually use the command center for detection, but it is limited in energy and not really useful. In the original StarCraft there's the Science Vessel... is there anything similar in SC2?

If there isn't anything similar - how to attack burrowed Zergs? I am worrying about their banelings burrowed in "main passes".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Raven](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Raven) more or less replaces the Science Vessel in SC2 as a flying detector + caster.  It doesn't have Irradiate but has other useful abilities like Auto-Turret, Point Defense Drone, and Seeker Missle (requires research)

If you're worried about burrowed banelings though you can always send out one unit first as a scout before moving out.  That's usually not a bad idea to do anyway.